# EmguCV and SURF: How to find largest area without any SURF point features?

Tags: c#, image-processing, emgucv, surf

I'm using C# with EmguCV in combination with a Kinect to display a video captured by the Kinect. My application detects successfully feature points with the SURF algorithm and marks them as red points on the video. Now I need to find and approximately largest area WITHOUT any feature points to detect a blank surface (e.g. free space for projection etc.). Is this possible using the SURF algorithm or do better solutions exist for this kind of problem?

Comment: don't use the tags "image" and "processing", use "image-processing". Processing is a programming language, and "image" is a mostly meaningless tag =)

Comment: Thanks. I didn't knew that Stackoverflow is providing a tag which includes both :D.